# How to simplify this expression of square roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

If one simplifies the infinite nested radical
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^8+\dots}}}}$$

Does one get $$\sqrt x\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$$
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write "\sqrt{x+\sqrt{y+2}}" between dollars to get $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{y+2}}$. For bigger, centered formulas, write then between two pairs of dollars.

Comment: @S.C.B Simplified answer is a product of square root of x and(1+sqrt(5))/2 . Not addition of square root of x and (1+sqrt(5))/2. Thanks S.C.B, ajotatxe and aakash for formatting/helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^8+\dots}}}}=\sqrt{x+x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{x+x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+1\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$
now let

$$y=\sqrt{1+1\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$
so
$$y^2-1=y$$
$$y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
select the $$y=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^8+\dots}}}}$$
$$ = \sqrt{x+x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$
$$ = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+1\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$

The continued square root $\sqrt{1+1\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$ is a well known form of $\phi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Alternative_forms)) and so you end up with:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{5}+1)}{2}$$
as required.